# [Python GTK+ 3]: MessageDialog: Set OK-button settings

Tags: python-3.x, dialog, gtk

I want that the button is disabled under some conditions with `set_sensitive(False)`.

The problem is that I don't know how I could call the ok or cancel button at the `MessageDialog`.

```
dialog_window = Gtk.MessageDialog(parent=None,
                                  flags=Gtk.DialogFlags.MODAL,
                                  type=Gtk.MessageType.QUESTION,
                                  buttons=Gtk.ButtonsType.OK_CANCEL,
                                  message_format="Edit username.")
```

I want something like `ok_button.set_sensitive(False)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
dialog.set_response_sensitive(Gtk.ResponseType.OK, False);
```

should set the sensitivity on all buttons with ResponseType OK.